# What is the Difference between Sorting and Optimize Sorting?

Tags: performance, sorting, optimization

I am beginner in programming.I have learn something about sorting.I heard a word name Optimize Sorting.I also heard from some people "How to optimize bubble sort or merge sort etc." and I don't know what's the difference between them.So can you please tell me what's the difference between them.

Comment: Maybe increasing bubble size to 3 can decrease total passes. This triples the number of in-bubble sorting but if it can divide total passes by 4, then its a gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the sentence. "Optimize Sorting" as a noun does not exist. It is a verb: "to optimize an existing sort algorithm". It should be clear what that means. It means creating a new algorithm that has the same structure as the old one, but is faster to execute.